# Como puedo conectar mi formulario html a mi base de datos llamando un procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo un formulario de HTML con 2 formularios, con los cuales tengo que registrar nuevos empleados y actualizar el suelo de los empleados, ya tengo el formulario hecho, pero mi codigo de PHP ha tenido unos cuantos problemas porque no envia la informacion puesta en mi formulario a la base de datos.Me gustaria que por favor me puedan ayudar  revisar qué está mal con mi codigo de php

Aquí mi codigo del formulario

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registro de nuevos empleados</title>
</head>
<body>
<body background="https://images4.alphacoders.com/667/667235.jpg">
<center>
<h1>Registre un nuevo empleado</h1>
<form action="index.php" >
Ingrese Id del empleado <input type="text" name="IdE" required> <br>
Ingrese Nombre del empleado <input type="text" name="NomE" required> <br>
Ingrese el apellido del empleado <input type="text" name="ApeE" required> <br>
Ingrese el sexo del empleado <input type="text" name="SexoE" required> <br>
Ingrese el sueldo del empleado <input type="text" name="SueldoE" required> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Registrar">
<input type="reset" value="Borrar">
</form>
<br><br>
        <h2>Actualice un registro</h2>
        <form form name="form"action="sueldoN.php" method="post">
        Ingrese Id del Empleado <input type="text" name="IdE"required> <br>
        Ingrese el sueldo nuevo del Empleado <input type="text" name="SueldoNuevo"required> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Actualizar">
        <input type="reset" value="Borrar">
        </form>
        </center>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Mi codigo de index.php de ingresar empleados

```
<?php


$bd = mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '','act_7');


$IdE=$_POST['IdE'];
$NomE=$_POST['NomE'];
$ApeE=$_POST['ApeE'];
$SexoE=$_POST['SexoE'];
$SueldoE=$_POST['SueldoE'];


$respuesta = mysqli_query($bd, 'CALL InsertaEmpleado($IdE, $NomE, $ApeE, $SexoE, $SueldoE)');
  


if($respuesta)
   echo "El usuario a sido registrado";
else
   echo "Ocurrió un error";
?>
```

Codigo sueldoN.php para actualizar el sueldo

```
<?php



$bd = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","act_7");


$IdE=$_POST["IdE"];
$SueldoNuevo=$_POST["SueldoNuevo"];


$respuesta = mysqli_query($bd, "CALL InsertaEmpleado($IdE,$SueldoNuevo)");
  


if($respuesta)
   echo "El usuario a sido registrado";
else
   echo "Ocurrió un error";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

En el primer Form te falta definir el método de posteo POST o GET, como no se ha definido se enviá por GET, por lo tanto para leerlo deberías usar

```
$IdE=$_GET['IdE'];
```

O de lo contrario poner en el formulario el método que gustes.

```
<form method="POST"> o <form method="GET">
```

Eso en cuanto a lo que se puede observar, ahora si hay un problema posterior, deberíamos echar una mirada a tu procedimiento almacenado.